# SQL Server Insert Statement From a CSV File

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I'm trying to follow the example on this page:

> http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/

The database is on another machine and I'm connecting to it using SQL Server Management Studio 2012.

Here's the insert statement

```
BULK
INSERT CSVTest
FROM '\\BPWKS\network share\csvtest.csv'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

When I go to check the content of the table, I get the following error:

> Error: Msg 208, Level 16, State 82, Line 1
>   Invalid object name 'CSVTest'.

*Table Definition*

```
Create Table CSVTest 
(
ID INT, 
FirstName VARCHAR(40), 
LastName VARCHAR(40), 
BirthDate SMALLDATETIME
) 
GO
```

I've also tried importing the local file at `'C:\csvtest.csv'`

Comment: is there a table called CSVTest in the schema your logged in as?  note the first thing he does in the link is create the table.  The error message you have either indicates incorrect permissions or missing table.

Comment: It successfully create the table then errors on the Bulk Inser

Comment: Create Table CSVTest
(ID INT,
FirstName VARCHAR(40),
LastName VARCHAR(40),
BirthDate SMALLDATETIME)
GO


BULK
 INSERT CSVTest
FROM 'c:\csvtest.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
--Check the content of the table.
SELECT *
FROM CSVTest
 GO

Comment: Msg 4860, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot bulk load. The file "c:\csvtest.csv" does not exist.

Comment: Ok, so now the question is Does the DB engine have permissions to see C:\csvtest.csv ON the server, or is the file on your local machine?  it sounds like a permissions issue or wherever the server is running doens't have a c:\csvtest.csv file.  It can't open the file.  Is the file there, does the server see it, does it have permissions to read it? lots of things to track down, take them one step at a time you'll get there.

Comment: Dunno who you are but your the man, Thank you!!!

Comment: Not really.  Just been around the same block a few times.  The trick I've learned is solve one problem at a time, and just like hooking up 3 gaming systems, a DVD, VCR, DVR and tv daisy chained back in the day... follow the wire (or data in this case) and think what needs to happen at each step for it to work.  You got there, you just wanted a sounding board.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution appears to be

1. Missing Table initially
2. Missing file or permissions to access
   file.